# Name topics in lda topic modeling based on beta values

Tags: r, ggplot2, lda

I'm currently trying to develop a code for a paper I have to write. I want to conduct a LDA-based topic modeling. I found some code deposits on GitHub and was able to combine them and slightly adapted them where necessary.
Now I would like to add something that would name each identified topic after the word with the highest beta-value assigned to the respective topic.
Any ideas? It's the first time I'm coding anything and my expertise is therefore quite limited.

Here's the section of the code where I wanted to insert the "naming part":

```
# get the top ten terms for each topic
  top_terms <- topics  %>% 
    group_by(topic) %>% # treat each topic as a different group
    top_n(10, beta) %>% # get top 10 words
    ungroup() %>% 
    arrange(topic, -beta) # arrange words in descending informativeness
   
# plot the top ten terms for each topic in order
    top_terms %>%
      mutate(term = reorder(term, beta)) %>% # sort terms by beta value 
      ggplot(aes(term, beta, fill = factor(topic))) + # plot beta by theme
      geom_col(show.legend = FALSE) + # as bar plot
      facet_wrap(~ topic, scales = "free") + # separate plot for each topic
      labs(x = NULL, y = "Beta") + # no x label, change y label 
      coord_flip() # turn bars sideways
```

I tried to insert it in this section of the code, but that didn't work.
I found this: [R topic modeling: lda model labeling function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16396090/r-topic-modeling-lda-model-labeling-function) but that didn't work for me, or I didn't get it.

I can't disclose more of the code, because there are some sensible data in there, but some expertise from the community would be highly appreciated nonetheless.

best regards and stay safe

Note: It say `top_terms` is a tibble. I tried to come up with some data of the top of my head.
The data in top_terms are structured exactly like this

topic   term    beta

```
(int)  (chr)  (dbl)
1   book    0,9876 
1   page    0,9765
1   chapter 0,9654
2   sports  0,8765
2   soccer  0,8654
2   champions   0,8543
3   music   0,9543
3   song    0,8678
3   artist  0,7231
4   movie   0,9846
4   cinema  0,9647
4   cast    0,8878
```

Comment: If you have sensitive data, can you generate a dummy dataset with the same structure (column names and types) as your `top_terms` data?

Comment: Please let me know, if this works as a dummy data set for `top_terms`. I wasn't sure

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can make an additional column in your data that, after grouping by topic, takes the name of the term with the highest beta.

```r
suppressPackageStartupMessages({
  library(ggplot2)
  library(tibble)
  library(dplyr)
})

# Just replicating example data
top_terms <- tibble(
  topic = rep(1:4, each = 3),
  term = c("book", "page", "chapter", 
           "sports", "soccer", "champions", 
           "music", "song", "artist",
           "movie", "cinema", "cast"),
  beta = c(0.9876, 0.9765, 0.9654,
           0.8765, 0.8654, 0.8543,
           0.9543, 0.8678, 0.7231,
           0.9846, 0.9647, 0.8878)
) 

top_terms %>%
  group_by(topic) %>%
  mutate(top_term = term[which.max(beta)]) %>%
  ggplot(aes(term, beta, fill = factor(topic))) +
  geom_col(show.legend = FALSE) +
  facet_wrap(~ top_term, scales = "free") +
  labs(x = NULL, y = "Beta") +
  coord_flip()
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2021-05-05 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v1.0.0)</sup>

Comment: Thanks a lot. That did the trick. Just what I was looking for. :)